# Joomla componente/module to list files on folders and group them by subfolders

Tags: list, joomla, file-management

Im new using Joomla version 2.5, and I need to show on an article or through a component or module, a the whole list of files stored on an specific folder with subfolders to guest users, in order to allow them downloading files from it. Also, I need to group them by subfolders.

I've search, but the most I can find is to show the directory tree to browse, and I don't wanna guest users to know the folder/subfolder structure.

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't really a StackOverflow question… anywho…*

An extension that comes to mind is [DOCman](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/10958) but I haven't used it for years and the learning curve used to be a bit steep.

I would suggest looking through the dozens of download extensions on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) ([JED](http://extensions.joomla.org)), specifically try the [Downloads section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads) or even maybe the [Paid Downloads](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/paid-downloads) section if you're looking for an eCommerce type solution.